# Rails 3 Notices don't work when using Redirect_To

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authlogic

I've got some code I have a :notice, which is only showing up selectively.

Here's the code

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @userhj.save
    format.html { redirect_to(:action => :index, :notice => 'Succesfully assigned job') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @userhj, :status => :created, :location => @userhj }
  else
    format.html { redirect_to(:root, :notice => 'Duplicate job assignment') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

When redirecting to :index from the :index view, the notices don't show up properly. Taking a look at Firebug's net console, there's a GET (insert url here)?notice=(notice text), which doesn't appear in other pages when the notices do show up correctly.

I'm using authlogic, just basic, set up using this tutorial http://www.logansbailey.com/2010/10/06/how-to-setup-authlogic-in-rails-3/. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing that Ruby is thinking that `:notice` is part of the url attribute rather than the options attribute. Try this:

```
redirect_to({:action => :index}, {:notice => 'Succesfully assigned job'})
```

Comment: Oh wow, that works perfectly! Can't tell you how crazy that's been driving me! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I had to pass a extra param and notice together. I couldn't get that working until I found your answer.
 
    redirect_to({:controller => 'sales', :action => 'new', :linked_id => @purchase.id}, { :notice => 'notice.'})