# redirect to index rather than show after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to redirect to the a models index view after saving my model.

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @test.save
      format.html { redirect_to @test, notice: 'test was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried

```
    format.html { render action: "index", notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
```

but I get the following error in /app/views/tests/index.html.erb -

```
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: where is that call to 'each'?

Comment: Edited question - it's in the index view.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
render action: "index"
```

will not redirect, redirecting and rendering a different, render will just render the view with the current available variables for it. while with a redirect the index function of the controller will run and then the view will be rendered from there.

you are getting the error because your index view is expecting some array which you are not giving to it since you are just rendering "index" and you dont have the variables that the view needs.

You can do it in 2 ways

1- using `render action: "index"`

make available to the view all the variables that it needs before you render, for example it may be needing a @posts variable which it uses to show list of posts so you need to get the posts in your create action before you render

```
@posts = Post.find(:all)
```

2- don't render do a `redirect_to`

instead of rendering "index" you redirect to the index action which will take care of doing the necessary things that the index view needs

```
redirect_to action: "index"
```

Comment: THanks, that works but my notice is not being displayed. I can see it's passed through as a url param /tests?notice=Test+was+successfully+created.

Comment: are you rendering the notice in your layout or the view somewhere ?

Comment: Yes I have <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> in my view. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: change it to `<p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p> `

Comment: It's a bit longer but you should probably use one of the *_url (such as `redirect_to posts_url`) methods. This fixed problem with my notice showing up.

Comment: Also see this to fix passing notices though redirect: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5853181/1795429

Answer (score 7):

The view "index" includes "@tests.each do"-loop. And method create does not provide the variable "@tests". so you have the error.
You can try this:

```
format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'Test was successfully created.' }
```

Comment: That works but my notice is not being displayed. I can see it's passed through as a url param /tests?notice=Test+was+successfully+created.

Comment: Try this: format.html { flash[:notice] = 'Test was successfully created.' and redirect_to action: "index" }

Comment: @user1297959 Could you update your answer to include your comment?  No other answer has it and it is very useful.

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple.

Just rewrite your method like

```
def create
  @test = Test.new(params[:test])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @test.save
      format.html { **redirect_to tests_path**, notice: 'test was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

It will redirect to the index page

Comment: items bracketed by ** is what needs to be changed from the default redirect.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Using the resource from the `rake routes`:

`format.html { redirect_to todo_items_url, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }`

2. Using the controller action:

`format.html { redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Todo item was successfully created.' }`

Comment: GOTCHA? Rails 4 on OSX 10.12, only the first method shoes the flash :notice item :)